# A User Signed in to Their HUAWEI ID, but No Authorization Code Was Returned. What Can I Do?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have integrated HUAWEI Account Kit into my app. However, after a user signed in to their HUAWEI ID, the error message Authorization code:null was displayed. Who can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/dev-guide-account-0000001050048888?ha_source=hms1) .
I think maybe your `HuaweiIdAuthParamsHelper.setAuthorizationCode` method was not called, which means your app may not be authorized to obtain the authorization code.

[image]